# xslt solution required for custom db collection

Tags: xslt

I need to transform from following source XML

```
<response_1 xmlns="http://www.example.org">
    <lines>
        <lineId>1</lineId>
        <item>item1</item>
        <configItem>
            <lineId>1</lineId>
            <configId>11</configId>
        </configItem>
        <configItem>
            <lineId>1</lineId>
            <configId>12</configId>
        </configItem>
    </lines>
    <lines>
        <lineId>2</lineId>
        <item>item2</item>
        <configItem>
            <lineId>2</lineId>
            <configId>21</configId>
        </configItem>
        <configItem>
            <lineId>2</lineId>
            <configId>22</configId>
        </configItem>
    </lines>
    <lines>
        <lineId>3</lineId>
        <item>item3</item>
     </lines>

</response_1>
```

to target XML as follows

```
<ns0:response_2 xmlns="http://www.example.org">
    <ns0:lines>
        <ns0:lineId>1</ns0:lineId>
        <ns0:item>item1</ns0:item>
        <ns0:configId>11</ns0:configId>
    </ns0:lines>
    <ns0:lines>
        <ns0:lineId>1</ns0:lineId>
        <ns0:item>item1</ns0:item>
        <ns0:configId>12</ns0:configId>
    </ns0:lines>
    <ns0:lines>
        <ns0:lineId>2</ns0:lineId>
        <ns0:item>item2</ns0:item>
        <ns0:configId>21</ns0:configId>
    </ns0:lines>
    <ns0:lines>
        <ns0:lineId>2</ns0:lineId>
        <ns0:item>item2</ns0:item>
        <ns0:configId>22</ns0:configId>
    </ns0:lines>
    <ns0:lines>
        <ns0:lineId>3</ns0:lineId>
        <ns0:item>item3</ns0:item>          
    </ns0:lines>
</ns0:response_2>
```

I have tried using creating Variable inside xslt but couldn't succeed. I am novice and request help here. Request your help here. I have edited the code with updated source and target here

Comment: Hi @Balaganesh, could you please post your code? It will then be easier to help you!

Comment: Thanks for quick response toti08. I can only post code tomorrow onceI login to my system.

Comment: Please note your target XML is not really valid, as you are using a prefix `ns0:` that is not bound to a namespace. Perhaps you mean to do `xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org"`? Having said that, whether you use a prefix, or a default namespace with no prefix should not really matter, just as long as the namespace URI is consistent.

Comment: This is the code I have used. I remove my variable declaration as it doesn't give any result   <xsl:template match="/"> <ns0:response_2>
         <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:response_1/ns0:lines/ns0:configItem">
            <ns0:lines><ns0:lineId><xsl:value-of select="ns0:lineId"/>               </ns0:lineId><ns0:item><xsl:value-of select="/ns0:item"/></ns0:item>               <ns0:configId> <xsl:value-of select="ns0:configId"/>
               </ns0:configId>
            </ns0:lines>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </ns0:response_2>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above have already suggested handling of the default namespace `http://www.example.org` using prefix or without prefix, however if the elements in the output XML require a prefix corresponding to the namespace, you can use the below templates to get the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org" > 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="ns0:response_1">
        <ns0:response_2>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ns0:response_2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:configItem">
        <ns0:lines>
            <ns0:lineId><xsl:value-of select="ns0:lineId" /></ns0:lineId>
            <ns0:item><xsl:value-of select="../ns0:item" /></ns0:item>
            <ns0:configId><xsl:value-of select="ns0:configId" /></ns0:configId>
        </ns0:lines>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:lines[not(ns0:configItem)]">
        <ns0:lines>
            <ns0:lineId><xsl:value-of select="ns0:lineId" /></ns0:lineId>
            <ns0:item><xsl:value-of select="ns0:item" /></ns0:item>
        </ns0:lines>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:lineId | ns0:item" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot. Let me put effort to understand how to group and sort elements.

Comment: I have one more line item which will not have configItem as follows. <lines>
    <lineId>3</lineId>
    <item>item3</item>
  </lines> I have added following template without deleting the above code.   <xsl:template match="ns0:lines"> <ns0:lines> <ns0:lineId><xsl:value-of select="ns0:lineId"/></ns0:lineId><ns0:item><xsl:value-of select="ns0:item"/> </ns0:item><ns0:configId><xsl:value-of select="ns0:configId"/></ns0:configId>
</ns0:lines></xsl:template>. But it doesn't produce the lineId--3 in <lines> at target response2. I tried in many combinations. Am I miss something here?

Comment: You need to update the question with the correct sample data. Changing requirements will not provide you with correct solutions.

Comment: I have edited the code in main section with updated source and required target.

Comment: Please refer to the updated solution. Going forward, do not add the code snippets in the comments section. It is not a good practice on SO and also does not help understand the code.

Comment: Exact answer to the issue. Will follow advice regarding not to code in comments. The code with " not " is directly understood. What does the code snippet <xsl:template match="ns0:lines[ns0:configItem]/ns0:configItem"> mean here. Is the [ns0:configItem] refers Index of the element here?

Comment: Please ignore that and retain the previous template.